# how can I add multiple travels information?

Tags: node.js

Here is my json data, I want to insert multiple travels information in `travelers`. Total numbers of travels may be given by the user.
In the below format I can just add one traveler.

```
 return amadeus.booking.flightOrders.post(
            JSON.stringify({
              'data':{
                'type': 'flight-order',
                'flightOffers': [response.data.flightOffers[0]],  
              
               'travelers':[{
                  "id": 1,
                  "name": {
                    "firstName": req.body.firstname,
                    "lastName": req.body.lastname
                  },
                  "gender": req.body.gender,
                  "contact": {
                    "emailAddress": req.body.emailaddress,
                    "phones": [{
                      "deviceType": req.body.devicetype,
                      "countryCallingCode": req.body.countrycallingcode,
                      "number": req.body.number
                    }]
                  },
                  "documents": [{
                    "documentType": req.body.documentype,
                    "birthPlace": req.body.birthplace,
                    "issuanceLocation": req.body.issuancelocation,
                    "issuanceDate": req.body.issuancedate,
                    "number": req.body.p_number,
                    "expiryDate": req.body.expirydate,
                    "issuanceCountry": req.body.issuancecountry,
                    "validityCountry": req.body.validitycountry,
                    "nationality": req.body.nationality,
                    "holder": true
                  }]
                }]
            } 
          })
          );
        }).then(function (response)
```

Comment: We would need more code to help you.
Plus this format is fine, see the `[` after travelers, that  means that a list.
The error must be in your javascript code.

Comment: So why not pushing as many travelers as you want to travelers array?

Answer (score 0):

`travelers` is an array. You can push multiple entries to it like

```js
data.travelers.push(traveler);
```

You can run get multiple traveler details in your API like:

```json
{
  "travelers": [{
     "firstname": "John",
     "secondname": "Doe",
   }, {
     "firstname": "Jane",
     "secondname": "Doe",
   }]
}
```

This can then be looped over to push multiple travelers in the `data` variable.

```js
let id = 1;
req.body.travelers.forEach(traveler => {
  data.travelers.push({
    id: id++,
    name: {
      firstName: traveler.firstname,
      lastName: traveler.lastname
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: still i can't get my output. Now i update code please review it sir.

Comment: The code in question doesn't tell many things. What is the desired output? What is the current output? Where are the multiple travelers' data?